# How can a 2 dimensional line integral of a vector field be represented graphically?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My goal is to understand how work that is calculated be either a 2 or 3 dimensional line integral of a vector field can be visually represented as a area , similarly to single variable calculus as work being the area under a curve.

My problem is that I need 3 dimensions for a 2 dimensional line integral to see this otherwise the path can loop back on itself.

As for example if the path is a helix in a 3 dimensional vector field then clearly it goes in a circle so loops around a three dimensional space.

Now imagine a path with a 2 dimensional vector field. Can this path loop on itself and how can **ANY** path end up being the area under a curve ?

Comment: Parameterizing the curve “straightens” it.

Comment: ...so this means the work is then the area under a curve ?  gee ...interesting

Comment: Just so. Remember, too, that unlike the pure one-dimensional case, the force can point in any direction, but only the part of in in the direction of motion contributes to the work.

Comment: i have been thinking about it and I can see how what you are saying might be true ...when the dot product is calculated the inputs to the force function are the points from the path through the vector field.   you refer to  "parameterizing". and now I can somewhat see intuitively why the choice of what is picked for the parameterizing makes no difference to the outcome.  ...but the fact that the direction does make a difference is another matter ,  I have to think about this more. on the other hand the path integral may generate an area under the path which represents work

Comment: Work is equal to the change in kinetic energy. Only tangential components of the force affect this, hence the dot product in one formulation of the line integral. A centripetal force that creates uniform circular motion does no work at all.